# get the largest number without an array

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get the largest number among the numbers the user give me without using a array, this is how i have done it:

```
let largestNum = 0
let userNum = 0
for(let i = 1; i<=3 ;i++){
    userNum = prompt("Give a number")
    if(userNum > largestNum){
        largestNum = userNum
    }
}document.write("the biggest number is: "+ largestNum)
```

Now, if im playing the user and insert first 10 and then 2 and 2, it print me that the largest number is 2! how come is it 2?!
after the first time the largest number should turn into 10, and from then, no number is larger than 10! so how come it i gives me 2?

Comment: `prompt` returns a string, and lexicographically `"2" > "10"` because `"2" > "1"`. The same way that `"b" > "ab"`.

Comment: You are my hero! that right! too bad i cant mark your answer as the correct one!